# Getting Direct message from twitter via api

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-oauth

I face a problem, while getting Direct message from twitter. 
{"errors":[{"code":93,"message":"This application is not allowed to access or delete your direct messages."}]}. 
I used the following url : 
api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/sent.json. Expecting your help.

Answer (score 4):

Regenerate your Access Token and Access Token Secret from the Application Management window on [enter link description here](https://apps.twitter.com/app/) and try refresh your bot

Answer (score 4):

In twitter app, in permissions tab select following option

Read, Write and Access direct messages

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Pekka. I solved this. The problem is, I had change access for token but, it displays same error. After changing the access, regenerating the access token would works.